# Informix compatible in memory Database for unit testing Java Hibernate application

Tags: hibernate, informix, in-memory-database

I'm trying to write unit test cases for a data access layer and we use the Informix database. Since the Informix dialect of SQL uses the `<databasename>@<server>:<owner>.<tablename>` name structure (with database, server and owner being optional), which in-memory database will support this notation, or is there any other way of escaping characters available.

Examples:

```
SELECT * FROM controldb@sphere_31:controller.control_directions AS cd
SELECT * FROM controldb:controller.control_directions AS cd
SELECT * FROM controldb@sphere_31:control_directions AS cd
SELECT * FROM controldb@control_directions AS cd
SELECT * FROM controller.control_directions AS cd
SELECT * FROM control_directions AS cd
```

Comment: I revised the question to match what I think you're asking.  I'm not sure whether there are any in-memory databases that support this notation.

Comment: Is it mandatory that you leave the full table name? In this example (which might be totally off base) you're just selecting the full tables. Couldn't this be `"SELECT * FROM " + TableName"`?